# android - static var is killed but activity is brought to foreground

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-state

let's say I have 2 activities A and B. I go to B from A then hit the Home button. there are a few static vars being initialized in A.

after a few hours or days or until activity is being killed, I launch the app again from the Recent button. activity B becomes the new entry point of this app, but static vars are no longer holding any value and has no chance of getting initialized unless I redirect back to A.

my `launchMode` for both activities are `singleTop`. not sure if that matters but I've tried `singleTop`, `singleInstance` and `standard` none of them work. I guess my expected behavior would be the entry point is always A or any other activities if is not being killed and of course static vars are still holding value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the problem may be because when your application is in background the android o.s must have cleaned the memory to free resources for other application

Comment: Are you sure, Android system being cleared the static value when memory is required?, If cleared what is the use of static concept?

Comment: i know activity may be killed. im looking for a solution. do u know if theres a way to always start with activity A if app is killed?

Answer (score 0):

- I hope those `static` variables are of primitive datatypes.
- Even if the Application is in background Android system kills the process after some time.
- So you can do is pass those primitive variables through `Intent` to `ActivityB`.
- Now if the Application is killed from background and brought it to Foreground same intent is used to launch the `ActivityB` and you can still get the passed variables.

Pass variable to `ActivityB` instead of static variable.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtras("Id", 1);
intent.putExtras("Name", "kevz");
startActivity(intent, ActivityB.class);
```

Now in `ActivityB` get the passed variable values-

```
int Id = getIntent().getIntExtra("Id", -1); // -1 is default value.
String Name = getIntent().getStringExtra("Name", "unknown"); // unknown is default value
```

Comment: no, those static vars are not all primitive type. if i had to pass vars through intent to activity B, whats the point of using static? and also if I had more activities, i then have to pass them all the way? i think i would prefer to start activity A if application is killed. any idea how that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

If static variables doesn't work, you can try using `getter()` and `setter()` methods for variables.